# Is python tuple assignment order fixed?

Tags: python, tuples, variable-assignment

Will

```
a, a = 2, 1
```

always result in a equal to 1? In other words, is tuple assignment guaranteed to be left-to-right?

The matter becomes relevant when we don't have just a, but a[i], a[j] and i and j may or may not be equal.

Comment: If C++ has taught us anything it's that empirical testing is not an appropriate way to understand the difference between well defined, implementation defined, and undefined behavior. You have to consult the language specification. Python isn't C++, but there are still dangerous parts, like how small integers are interned, that can vary between interpreters.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is part of the Python language reference that tuple assignment must take place left to right.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that
> this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter
> yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of
> the target lists, from left to right.

So all Python implementations should follow this rule.

Personally, I would still be hesitant to use this as it seems unclear to a future reader of the code.

Answer (score 1):

How it works :

```
a, a = 2, 1
--> a does not exist, create variable a and set value to 2
--> a already exists, value of a changed to 1
```

When you have different variables, it works exactly the same way :

```
a, b, a = 1, 2, 3
--> a does not exist, create variable a and set value to 1
--> b does not exist, create variable b and set value to 2
--> a already exists, value of a changed to 3
```