# Why does this Python snippet regarding dictionaries work?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say we have this

```py
>>> x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> y = {}
>>> for k, y[k] in x.items(): pass
...
>>> y
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Why does this work?

Note: I saw this first [here](https://twitter.com/treyhunner/status/1451592709798604800?s=20)

Comment: Not dissimilar to `a,b = 1,2` presumably. Effectively `k, y[k] = <the key>, <the value>`.

Comment: That is disgusting :D

Comment: `y[k]` is assigned during each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Same as if you were to use the variables in a for loop. ```for k, y[k] in x.items(): print(y[k])```. The for loop assigns y[k] to the second argument of an element of x.items(). Pretty cool though, didn't know about this.

Comment: Depends on fixed, left-to-right assignment order. Asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855410/is-python-tuple-assignment-order-fixed/39855637)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a, b = (c, d)` unpacks the tuple from left to right and assigns `a = c` and `b = d` in that order.

`x.items()` iterates over key-value pairs in `x`. E.g. doing `list(x.items())` will give `[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]`

`for a, b in x.items()` assigns the key to `a`, and the value to `b` for each key-value pair in `x`.

`for k, y[k] in x.items()` assigns the key to `k`, and the value to `y[k]` for each key-value pair in `x`.

You can use `k` in `y[k]` because `k` has already been assigned since unpacking happens left-right

You don't need to do anything in the loop because whatever you needed is done already.

Because the loop already assigned every value in `x` to `y[k]`, `y` is now a shallow copy of `x`.

As the tweet you reference says, this is indeed a *"terse, unintuitive, and confusing"* way to do `x.copy()`

Answer (score 3):

This is a remarkably odd way to use the loop binding. For each item, the tuple of `(key, value)` is assigned into `k, y[k]`. Both instances of `k` refer to the same variable, so the [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) `y[k]` assigns into the dictionary `y`. This relies on a destructuring assignment being solved left to right; using `y[k], k` doesn't work as `k` isn't assigned the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The iterating variable is assigned values as it iterates through the iterable. In your case, `k, y[k]` are assigned with `(key, value)` from `dict.items()`.

In your case `y[k]` actually calls `dict.__setitem__` here which is why your `y` gets updated.

Example,

```
class T():
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f"Assigning {key} with value {value}")


x = {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 4}
val = T() 

for k, val[k] in x.items():
    pass

Assigning a with value 2
Assigning b with value 3
Assigning c with value 4
```

In your case `dict.__setitem__` is called while iterating through `x.items()` and `dict.__setitem__` mutates your dict `y` so eventually you are copying `x` dict into `y`.

---

As an aside:
I have one more "obnoxious, unintuitive, and confusing" way to copy a dict.

```
x  = {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
it = iter(x.items())
y  = {}
[*iter(lambda : y.__setitem__(*next(it)), "Is this confusing enough??")]
print(y)
# {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```